# python string to elements, apostrophe remove

Tags: python, string, function, variables, apostrophe

I have a function which fills in a DatFrame. In the first example I have fixed number of elements x[0]...x[5].

```
def chyt(ftch):
    vl=[]
    for x in ftch:
       val= [x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]] 
       vl.append(val)
    return vl
```

It works

Because x is a result of ftch=cursor.fetchall() and I have many different selects(PYODBC) and the number of elements changes, I need formula which allows adding parameter with length of the source list in the function.

Somthing like that:

```
def chyt(ftch, lng):  
   vl=[]
   for x in ftch:
       val= [f"x[{b}]" for b in range(lng)]
       vl.append(val)
   return vl
```

But

```
val= [f"x[{b}]" for b in range(lng)]


produces *['x[0]', 'x[1]', 'x[2]']*
```

not required

```
[x[0], x[1], x[2]]
```

In result it does not work
Can anbydy help me ?

Nice day,

Jan

P.S.I am sorry for nesting, I am sending first time a post here.

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: It si not working

Comment: It is not working, I would like replace val= [x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]]

Comment: by something like that

Comment: val= [f"x[{b}]" for b in range(lng)]

Comment: Can't you just do `vl.append(x)`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify, code is hard to read in comments. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the second one is the usage of the f-string. If you want the result to be a list instead of the tuple that `cursor.fetchall()` returns, you can just do `vl.append(list(x))`

See the logic below for a simple demostration:

```py
t = (2,3,545,6) # tuple
l = [] 
l.append(list(t))
l.append(list(t)) # append twice to show it's a list of lists
print(l)
```

**output**

```py
[[2, 3, 545, 6], [2, 3, 545, 6]]
```

To apply this to your logic, see the code below:

```py
def chyt(ftch):  
   result = []
   for row in ftch:
       result.append(list(row))
   return result
```

just as a sidenote, try to give variables meaningful names. It makes it a lot easier to read the code